# Finding $\sin 2\alpha$, given $\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}+\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$. (Where's my error?)

Tags: trigonometry

The problem:

> If $$\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{2},$$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}\lt \alpha \lt 2\pi,$ find $\sin2\alpha.$

It looks like an ordinary one, so I raised both sides of the first expression to quadrat and had 
$$\begin{align}\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)+\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)+2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)&=\phantom{-}\frac{1}{4}\\[6pt] 
1+\sin(2\alpha)&=\phantom{-}\frac{1}{4}\\[6pt] 
\sin(2\alpha)&=-\frac{3}{4} \end{align}$$ But there is no such an answer, so any hints concerning this issue will be helpful!

Comment: Make that $\sin\alpha=-3/4$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I didn't understand. Do you mean just substituting?

Comment: it is $$2\sin(\alpha/2)\cos(\alpha/2)=\sin(\alpha)$$

Comment: You made two mistakes: squaring introduces alein solutions and $2\cdot\alpha/2=\alpha$.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no such answer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second last displayed line should read

$$1+\sin \alpha = \frac{1}{4}$$

since you're doubling $\alpha/2$.  So $\sin \alpha = -3/4.$  Then you have, since you're in the 4th quadrant and cosine is positive there:

$$\sin 2\alpha = 2\sin \alpha \cos \alpha = 2\frac{-3}{4}\sqrt{1- \left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^2 }= \frac{-3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{7}{16} }.$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use that $$\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})+\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Shouldn't that $x$ be $\alpha$?

Comment: yes now it is $\alpha$ thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

it is

$$
2\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2})=\sin \alpha
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + \cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = - \frac 12$

$(\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + \cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}})^2 = (-\frac 12)^2 = \frac 14$.

Pitfall but not an error, solving for this will also solve for $\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + \cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}} =  \frac 12$

$\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}+\cos^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + 2\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = \frac 14$

$1 + \sin{2*\frac{\alpha}2} = \frac 14$.

Error   $2\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = \sin{2*\frac{\alpha}2} \ne \sin{2\alpha}$.

$\sin \alpha = -\frac 34$

$\sin(2\alpha) = 2\sin \alpha \cos \alpha$

$= 2*(-\frac 34)(\pm \sqrt{1-(-\frac 34)^2})$

$= (-\frac 32)(\sqrt{\frac 7{16}})$ ($\cos \alpha > 0$ as $\frac {3\pi}{2} < \alpha < 2\pi$)

$=- \frac {3\sqrt{7}}8$